# C# regular expression for finding a certain pattern in a text

Tags: c#, regex, text-extraction

I'm trying to write a program that can replace bible verses within a document with any desired translation. This is useful for older books that contain a lot of KJV referenced verses. The most difficult part of the process is coming up with a way to extract the verses within a document.

I find that most books that place bible verses within the text use a structure like `"N"(BookName chapter#:verse#s)`, where N is the verse text, the quotations are literal and the parens are also literal. I've been having problems coming up with a regular expression to match these in a text.

The latest regular expression I'm trying to use is this: `\"(.+)\"\s*\(([\w. ]+[0-9\s]+[:][\s0-9\-]+.*)\)`. I'm having trouble where it won't find all the matches.

Here is the regex101 of it with a sample. https://regex101.com/r/eS5oT8/1

Is there anyway to solve this using a regular expression? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot the global flag, Stick a `g` in the box to the right in your regex101 example.  If this is not working with .Matches in C#, show us that code.

Comment: Use the "g" modifier so it won´t stop at first match

Comment: Use g switch to match all.

Comment: "/ \"(.+)\"\s*\(([\w. ]+[0-9\s]+[:][\s0-9\-]+.*)\)/g"

Comment: see the link i have updated https://regex101.com/r/eS5oT8/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth mentioning that the site you were using to test this relies on Javascript Regular Expressions, which require the `g` modifier to be explicitly defined, unlike C# (which is global by default).

You can adjust your expression slightly and ensure that you escape your double-quotes properly :

```
// Updated expression with escaped double-quotes and other minor changes
var regex = new Regex(@"\""([^""]+)\""\s*\(([\w. ]+[\d\s]+[:][\s\d\-]+[^)]*)\)");
```

And then use the [`Regex.Matches()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find all of the matches in your string :

```
// Find each of the matches and output them
foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(input))
{
     // Output each match here (using Console Example)
     Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

You can see it in action in [this working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pdIn9g) with example output seen below :

[image]

Comment: I think I may of found a new problem. What do you do for verses that contain a set of quotes with them? There are many verses that have this, and with this reg exp it seems to break. For instance, "This is a new message, "go and have fun". The people were amazed." (book 3:2). With the current reg exp, it will capture from "go and have fun..., but I would want it to capture the whole thing from "This is a new message, because that would be the whole verse if it did contain a quote within.

Comment: You could explicitly tell the expression that you know it will end when a `)` is reached. So if you were to change your expression slightly to `@"\""([^\)]+)\""\s*\(([\w. ]+[0-9\s]+[:][\s0-9\-]+[^)]*)\)"`, it should resolve your issue as seen [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CTiLSa)

Comment: This works for quotes. But there are also some verses with parens in them. Which breaks the match as well. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: It may get quite tough as you'll need some type of standardized pattern that you'll be able to use to recognize when a specific quote ends and when another one begins. You could handle it via a `:` which would work for inner-quotes and inner-parentheses, but it would break for any verses that contained a `:` via : `@"\""([^:]+)\""\s*\(([\w. ]+[0-9\s]+[:][\s0-9\-]+[^)]*)\)"` as seen [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ldUBuG)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "g" modifier.

> g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

See the  [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS5oT8/2)

Answer (score 1):

you can try with example given in MSDN here is the link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "ablaze beagle choral dozen elementary fanatic " +
                     "glaze hunger inept jazz kitchen lemon minus " +
                     "night optical pizza quiz restoration stamina " +
                     "train unrest vertical whiz xray yellow zealous";
      string pattern = @"\b\w*z+\w*\b";
      Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
      while (m.Success) {
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at position {1}", m.Value, m.Index);
         m = m.NextMatch();
      }   
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    'ablaze' found at position 0
//    'dozen' found at position 21
//    'glaze' found at position 46
//    'jazz' found at position 65
//    'pizza' found at position 104
//    'quiz' found at position 110
//    'whiz' found at position 157
//    'zealous' found at position 174
```

Answer (score 1):

How about starting with this as a guide:

```
(?<quote>"".+"")          # a series of any characters in quotes 
\s +                      # followed by spaces
\(                        # followed by a parenthetical expression
   (?<book>\d*[a-z.\s] *) # book name (a-z, . or space) optionally preceded by digits. e.g. '1 Cor.'
   (?<chapter>\d+)        # chapter e.g. the '1' in 1:2
   :                      # semicolon
   (?<verse>\d+)          # verse e.g. the '2' in 1:2
\)
```

Using the options:

```
RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```

The expression above will give you named captures of every element in the match for easy parsing (e.g., you'll be able to pick out quote, book, chapter and verse) by looking at, e.g., `match.Groups["verse"]`.

Full code:

```
var input = @"Jesus said, ""'Love your neighbor as yourself.' 
            There is no commandment greater than these"" (Mark 12:31).";

var bibleQuotesRegex =
    @"(?<quote>"".+"")              # a series of any characters in quotes 
    \s +                            # followed by spaces
    \(                              # followed by a parenthetical expression
            (?<book>\d*[a-z.\s] *)  # book name (a-z, . or space) optionally preceded by digits. e.g. '1 Cor.'
            (?<chapter>\d+)         # chapter e.g. the '1' in 1:2
            :                       # semicolon
            (?<verse>\d+)           # verse e.g. the '2' in 1:2
    \)";
foreach(Match match in  Regex.Matches(input, bibleQuotesRegex, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    var bibleQuote = new
    {
        Quote = match.Groups["quote"].Value,
        Book = match.Groups["book"].Value,
        Chapter = int.Parse(match.Groups["chapter"].Value),
        Verse = int.Parse(match.Groups["verse"].Value)
    };

    //do something with it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've added "g", also be careful if there are multiple verses without any `'\n'` character in between, because `"(.*)"` will treat them as one long match instead of multiple verses. You will want something like `"([^"]*)"` to prevent that.